# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors - ggtern

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

Disclaimer: new to R.

Hello! I'm trying to plot ternary diagrams of water chemistry samples using the `ggtern` package. Trying to run the following code gets me the title error.

```
require(ggtern)

datos = read.csv("Li, B, Cl.csv", header = T, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(datos) <- c("Muestra", "Li", "B", "Cl")

x11()
plot <- ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(datos[["Li"]]), y = as.numeric(datos[["Cl"]]), z = as.numeric(datos[["B"]]))) + geom_point()
plot
```

From my understanding, there is some low level function expecting an atomic vector, but I'm giving `ggtern`, as an input, a data.frame (checked through `str()`).

Once executed, the script draws nothing. My data is formatted as it follows, but semicolon-separated:

`Muestra    Li  B   Cl
XYA3030 2.321334755 3.017842551 94.66082269
XEP3609 9.436334248 45.43581846 45.12784729
XEP3606_1   10.12604478 62.68726944 27.18668578
XEP3606_2   5.18367492  34.94305194 59.87327314
XEP3611 5.859786577 18.8098607  75.33035272
XEP3613 13.60173875 49.1191375  37.27912375
XEP3612 13.11960754 27.07316925 59.80722321
XEP3608 6.473636887 15.58523589 77.94112722
XEP3543 16.93515603 46.59573787 36.4691061`

This is the "dput(datos)" output, as suggested in the comments.

```
> dput(datos)

structure(list(Muestra = c("XYA3030", "XEP3609", "XEP3606_1", 
"XEP3606_2", "XEP3611", "XEP3613", "XEP3612", "XEP3608", "XEP3543"
), Li = c(2.321334755, 9.436334248, 10.12604478, 5.18367492, 
5.859786577, 13.60173875, 13.11960754, 6.473636887, 16.93515603
), B = c(3.017842551, 45.43581846, 62.68726944, 34.94305194, 
18.8098607, 49.1191375, 27.07316925, 15.58523589, 46.59573787
), Cl = c(94.66082269, 45.12784729, 27.18668578, 59.87327314, 
75.33035272, 37.27912375, 59.80722321, 77.94112722, 36.4691061
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

**Update: tried the simplest code I could come up with and still no luck. Am I missing something basic?**

```
library(ggtern)
datos = read.csv("Li_B_Cl.csv", header = T, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes(x = Li, y = Cl, z = B)) + geom_point()
```

**Update 2**: cleared the RStudio session and packages, reinstalled ggtern and ggplot2, then ran the simple code. No luck. Here's the traceback after the error:

```
> datos = read.csv("Li_B_Cl.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes(x = Li, y = Cl, z = B)) + geom_point()
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> traceback()
17: transform_position(data, panel_params$x$rescale, panel_params$y$rescale)
16: f(...)
15: self$super()$super()$transform(data, scale_details)
14: f(..., self = self)
13: self$transform(ex, scale_details)
12: .get.tern.extremes(self, list(x.range = self$limits$x, y.range = self$limits$y))
11: f(..., self = self)
10: self$coord$setup_panel_params(scale_x, scale_y, params = self$coord_params)
9: (function (scale_x, scale_y) 
   {
       self$coord$setup_panel_params(scale_x, scale_y, params = self$coord_params)
   })(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]])
8: mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
7: Map(setup_panel_params, scales_x, scales_y)
6: f(..., self = self)
5: layout$setup_panel_params()
4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
3: ggplot_build(x)
2: print.ggplot(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

Comment: Hi Felipe. Please make your post reproducible by including representative & minimal sample data, e.g. using `dput(datos)` and then copy & pasting the output here.

Comment: don't subset your data in `aes` like you do - just use the names of the columns./ variables

Comment: @MauritsEvers, thank you, just edited and included my data as selectable text and the dput output.

Comment: @Tjebo (...)aes(x = "Li", y = "Cl"), z = "B")(...) did not solved the issue.

Comment: `aes(x=Li, y=CI)`?

Comment: Typically, `aes` takes names, not strings. If you want to use strings, there is `aes_string` for passing the variables either as strings or programmatically via variables (that are strings indicating the column names).

Answer (score 2):

Changing to *names* within `aes` fixes it for me:

```r
library(ggtern)
ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes(x = Li, y = Cl, z = B)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggtern]

In general, `aes` uses *names* (or *symbols*), meaning unquoted. There are times when this is not desirable, such as when either you don't know the name ahead of time or want to do it programmatically for another reason. In cases where you have strings of variable names, one can also do:

```r
ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes_string(x = "Li", y = "Cl", z = "B")) + geom_point()
```

(or `var1 <- "Li"`, then `aes_string(x=var1, ...)`).

There are other `rlang`-ways of doing things using quos and such, not necessarily relevant to your question.

Another thing to consider is that generally you refer to the variables and not the vectors. In your code, you had `x = as.numeric(datos[["Li"]])` which is trying to pass a vector of values. This seems like it makes sense, though it won't work. One reason it's best to allow `ggplot2` (and `ggtern`, by inheritance) to manage the data is to do some tricks that would otherwise require a bit more external/manual tracking. For instance, you can have a layer work on just a subset of the data:

```r
ggtern(data = datos, mapping = aes(x = Li, y = Cl, z = B)) + geom_point() +
  geom_point(color = "red", data = ~ subset(., grepl("XYA", Muestra)))
# the "." means "data as it exists so far" ^^^
```

(which colors the one point "red" without having to deal with subsetting it yourself). This is especially useful when the data you pass to `ggplot(data=...)` or `ggplot(data=...)` is pre-filtered and/or at the end of a pipe, where you would otherwise have to recreate the data in layers. So ... use names/symbols, don't try to use vectors.

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. But still no luck.  Got to the most simplified form of my code and couldn't get past the same error.I'm starting to think that it has to do something with the installation of RStudio, RTools or the packages themselves.

Comment: Given that this code works with the data sample that you provided, that suggests that the data sample is not representative of your real data. I've tried some randomly-placed `NA`s and could not reproduce the error. Here's what I suggest: close and restart R, *fresh* (no use of `.Rdata`). Reinstall `ggtern`. Reload your data just as you've shown above. Try again. If you get the error, immediately run `traceback()` and post the output in your question.

Comment: IIRC `aes_string` is deprecated, sadly (it's the only sensible interface for programming imo).

Comment: @r2evans Just updated the question with the traceback output. The data sample IS the real data. Thank you for your time!

Comment: That is breaking in `ggplot2:::transform_position`, not in `ggtern`. Try reinstalling `ggplot2`.

Comment: Tried that, ggplot2 is working fine. Still the same error. I was able to plot just 2 of my columns in an XY plot, though.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error given ggplot2-3.2.1, ggtern-3.1.0, R-3.5.3 (win10), and your data above.

Comment: Just posted an answer with what solved my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled the packages version indicated by @r2evans (ggplot2-3.2.1, ggtern-3.1.0) manually using `install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="source")` and surprise! It worked. I'm running R 3.6.3, if that's relevant.

Comment: Changes in ggplot3.3.0 appear to broken ggtern. https://bitbucket.org/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/10/two-errors-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic

Comment: Same here. `devtools::install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.2.1")` and it worked.